# Initiate EC2 Instance Shutdown via EstimatedCharges Threshold

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am using **[amazon-ec2](/questions/tagged/amazon-ec2)** and currently have a couple of [CloudWatch](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/) Alarms set using the `EstimatedCharges` Threshold at different price ranges.

While my request here would obviously be a last/worst case situation, I am wondering how it would be possible to do this, if it even is.

What I am wanting to do is to setup an `alarm` that will *(somehow, how??)* initiate a `Shutdown` of a specific EC2 `Instance` when a specific alarm goes from a state of `OK` to a state of `ALARM` ?

I do not want to `TERMINATE` the instance, just a `SHUTDOWN`.

The idea here being making sure that a monthly bill does not all of a sudden go way beyond what can be afforded, even if it does mean shutting down the entire server.

Maybe there is another/better method of doing what I am after via another AWS service, if so, would love to know about that.